# Delphi Using Locate function in data source in memory table

Tags: delphi

I need to check given value is already exists in the memory table, so i have tried  following method.

```
function TForm4.findValueExists(id: Integer): Boolean;
var
  state: Boolean;
begin
  state := DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Locate('code', id, []);

end;
```

here is the Search button procedure

```
procedure TForm4.butSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  id: Integer;
  Name: String;
  Sell: Double;

  Qty: Integer;
  Amount: Double;
  OldQty: Integer;
  RecordExist: Boolean;
begin

  if txtprocode.Text <> '' then

  begin

    FDQuery1.Params.ParamByName('ID').Value := txtprocode.Text;
    if FDQuery1.Active then
      FDQuery1.Close;
    FDQuery1.Open();

    try
      FDQuery1.First;
      if not FDQuery1.Eof then
      begin
        id := FDQuery1.FieldByName('Id').AsInteger;
        Name := FDQuery1.FieldByName('name').AsString;
        Sell := FDQuery1.FieldByName('selling').AsFloat;
        Qty := 1;
        Amount := Sell * Qty;

        if Form4.findValueExists(id) then
        begin
          FDMemTable1.Edit;
          OldQty := DBGrid1.Fields[3].Value;

          FDMemTable1.FieldByName('Qty').AsInteger := (OldQty + 1);
          FDMemTable1.FieldByName('amount').AsFloat := (Sell * (OldQty + 1));
          FDMemTable1.Post;

        end
        else
        begin
          FDMemTable1.InsertRecord([id, Name, Sell, Qty, Amount]);
        end;

      end;
    finally

    end;

  end;
end;
```

unfortunately this method always gives me result as 'false'. but physically i can found matched result for given id. 
here is  UI
[image]

[image]

Guys i`m new to Delphi language.

Comment: You don't assign state to the result of your function, so at the moment, nothing assigns a return value for findValueExists.

Comment: I have removed the assigned variable and run it again , same thing happens

Comment: "same thing happens"  In that case, update the code in your q so that it is what you are now using and add the code you use to call findValueExists().

Comment: #kobik# its not worked

Comment: I have updated the question ,

Comment: `function TForm4.findValueExists(id: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Locate('code', id, []);

end;`

Comment: You don't need the `Form4.` in `Form4.findValueExists(id)` and it will cause problems if the instance of TForm4 you are using isn't the auto-created one.

Comment: Neither of the images you posted was necessary. We don't care one iota about your UI unless the question is about the UI. Images should be used only for things that can't be demonstrated by any other means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning a value from your `FindValueExists` function, so you have absolutely no way of knowing if it locates the record or not. If you'd turn on compiler hints and warnings, the compiler would have pointed that fact out to you. (It would have informed you *function findValueExists might not return a value*, and also that *Value assigned to 'state' is never used*.)

Change your `findValueExists` so that it actually returns the result of the `Locate` call.

```
function TForm4.findValueExists(id: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Locate('code', id, []);
end;
```

Comment: I have changed it.. nothing happen , It always return false anyway.

Comment: Its solved.I did call function with ' TForm4', means  TForm4.findValueExists(1)

Comment: No, using `TForm4.findValueExists()` is incorrect. Use either `findValueExists()` or `Self.findValueExists()`.